# SAML Integration with IdentityServer4 using Saml2p

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, saml-2.0, asp.net-core-2.2

I am following [SAML 2.0 Integration with IdentityServer4](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/saml-20-integration-with-identityserver4) and implementing "IdentityServer 4 as a SAML Service Provider".

I also read [Automatic Metadata Lookup](https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/saml2p/config-sp/metadata/) and configured my startup as given below

```
authenticationBuilder = authenticationBuilder.AddSaml2p("saml2p", options =>
    {

        options.Licensee = "DEMO";
        options.LicenseKey = "<<LICENSE_KEY>>";
        options.IdentityProviderMetadataAddress = "https://degreed.com/saml/idp/94";


        options.ServiceProviderOptions = new SpOptions
        {
            EntityId = "https://degreed.com/DegreedIdP/94",
            MetadataPath = "/saml/metadata",

            // optional
            //SignAuthenticationRequests = true,
            //SigningCertificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String("<<SOME_STRING>>"))
        };

        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv";
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    });
```

I am getting the IdendityServer login screen with one of the external providers as SAML2P, but when I click on it, it redirects to https://localhost:44380/External/Challenge?provider=saml2p&returnUrl=%2Fgrants and I can see a blank page. When I check in the IdentityServer logs it says "`System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://degreed.com/saml/idp/94'. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more values could not be parsed from the metadata document. See inner exceptions for details. (Unable to parse a value for SigningCertificate from the metadata document) ---> IdentityServer4.Saml.Exceptions.SamlXmlParsingException: Unable to parse a value for SigningCertificate from the metadata document`"

Answer (score 0):

The first link is broken?

Does the metadata have a signature element?

Try setting "SignAuthenticationRequests" to "False".

What happens when you enter the metadata manually as per the second article?